# PHP Form Overflow and Alignment

Tags: css, forms

Thank you for taking the time to read/answer this.

First thing: [my career page](http://www.ocalaplastering.com/career.php) has a pre-made contact form that i turned into a job application. I have two layout questions:

1.) How do i get the 'checkbox' buttons to line up a little closer to each other. I tried td colspan="2" which is the case later in the form for 2 buttons (submit/reset 1 which i removed), but to no avail, "No" appears well to the right of "Yes." I'd like to have it relatively closer to "Yes."

2.) When you pull the drop down for "Experience" down, it forces the image below the form. Once you select your option, the image goes back to its place. Do i absolutely have to absolute position the graphic? Or can i add an overflow maybe to the dropdown? I can't figure it out.

[FancyForm](http://tutorialzine.com/2014/04/creative-company-bootstrap-template/) is the form i'm using.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="submit.php">
                              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="name">Name</label></td>
                                  <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter]]" name="name" id="name" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['name']?>" /></td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="address">Address</label></td>
                                  <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[a-zA-Z\d\s\-\,\#\.\+]+]" name="address" id="address" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['address']?>" /></td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="telephone">Telephone</label></td>
                                  <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['telephone']?>" /></td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="email">Email</label></td>
                                  <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['email']?>" /></td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="citizenship">US Citizen</label></td>
                                  <td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="citizen" value="yes">Yes</td>
                                  <td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="citizen" value="no">No</td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="age">At Least 18</label></td>
                                  <td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="age" value="yes">Yes</td>
                                  <td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="age" value="no">No</td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="previousexp">Have you worked<br> with us before?</label></td>
                                  <td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="previousexp" value="yes">Yes
                                  <td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="previousexp" value="no">No</td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="subject">Experience</label></td>
                                  <td width="70%"><select name="subject" id="subject">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected"> - Choose -</option>
                                    <option value="0-5">0-5 Years</option>
                                    <option value="6-10">6-10 Years</option>
                                    <option value="11-15">11-15 Years</option>
                                    <option value="16-20">16-20 Years</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                              <td><label for="captcha"><?=$_SESSION['n1']?> + <?=$_SESSION['n2']?> =</label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" name="captcha" id="captcha" /></td>
                              <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />                              
                              <?=$str?>          <img id="loading" src="img/ajax-load.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" /></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          </form>
```

CSS:

```
#form-container{
    padding:0px;
}

td{
    white-space:nowrap;
}

h1{
    color:#777777;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

h2{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:10px; 
    text-transform:uppercase;   
    color:#aaaaaa;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #484848;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

label{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Tahoma,Arial,Sans-serif;
}

textarea{
    color:#404040;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

td > button{
    text-indent:8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify static percentile widths on the check boxes in question.

Use the:

```
margin-left:15px;
/* & */
margin-right:15px;
```

CSS properties on the checkboxes... To do this I would recommend giving the checkboxes a class of:

```
class="chk-close"
```

...or something meaningful... then use the class declaration, declared with a '.' (period / full stop) adding the new CSS declaration into your external CSS file.

aka:

```
.chk-close
{
    margin: 0px -15px 0px -15px;
    /* Will do all top, right, bottom, left... margin amounts */
}
```

Please comment on this if you would like any further support!